# videojs player seek buttons works in other browsers but not in chrome. The video starts again on clicking the progress bar

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-s3, html5-video, video.js

I'm fetching a video from s3 bucket using django(backend) and then playing the video in react (frontend) but the seek controls work in other browsers but not in chrome. The video starts again on clicking the progress bar or clicking the arrow keys. I don't understand what seems to be the problem.

here is my django code for fetching video

```
class GenericFileOperation(APIView):
    def get(self, request, material_type=None, course_id=None, format=None):
        key = request.GET.get('key')
        download = request.GET.get('download')

        if key is not None:
            s3_obj = download_assessment_file(key)
            splited_path = key.split("/")
            file_name = splited_path[len(splited_path)-1]
            contents = s3_obj['Body'].read()
            temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
            temp.write(contents)
            temp.seek(0)
            mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(key)
            response = HttpResponse(temp, content_type=mime_type)
            if download is not None:
                response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % (
                    file_name)
            response['X-Frame-Options'] = "*"
            return response
```

here is my code for videojs in react

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import VideoJs from 'video.js'
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';
import "videojs-hotkeys";
import 'videojs-seek-buttons'

const videoJsOptions = {
    controls: true,
    autoplay: false,
    fluid: true,
    loop: false,
    playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
    aspectRatio: '12:5',
    plugins: {
        seekButtons: {
            forward: 30,
            back: 10
        },
        hotkeys: {}
    }
}

const VideoPlayer = ({ url, fileType }) => {
    const videoContainer = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        videoContainer.current.innerHTML = `
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video data-setup='{"fluid": true, "autoplay":true,"html5": {"vhs": 
        {"overrideNative": true}, "nativeAudioTracks": false, "nativeVideoTracks": false}}' class="video-js" />
      </div>
    `

        const player = VideoJs(videoContainer.current.querySelector('video'), videoJsOptions, async () => {
            player.src({ src: url, type: fileType })
        })

        //  When destruct dispose the player
        return () => player.dispose()
    }, [url, fileType])

    return <div ref={videoContainer} />
}

export default VideoPlayer
```

Thank you in advance

I tried using different plugins of videojs but nothing solves the problem. Please help if you have any idea

Comment: When seeking the browser request includes a range header specifying part of the video file. Your server must return that part and not the whole file. Safari probably won't play the file at all.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion as to how I can handle it in django

Comment: I've no idea how to implement that in Django, hence the comment rather than the answer. But that is the problem.